# Get Sum of elements using js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, reduce

I have array. Every element in this array is object, that contains also array. 
So I need to get sum of every items in array, that exists in array.

I have tried next :

```
function getSum(total, item) {
    return total + item;
}

var sum = array.reduce((total, item) => total + item.data.reduce(getSum));
```

But It returns not sum, but string, which starts with `Object`...

Comment: Show the value of `array`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set [an initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for `total`:

```
var sum = array.reduce((total, item) => total + item.data.reduce(getSum, 0), 0);
```

If you don't, it will be initialized with the first item of the array, which in your case is an object. That's why you're getting that unexpected string.

You can even shorten your code by using `total` as the initial value for the second reduction:

```
var sum = array.reduce((total, item) => item.data.reduce(getSum, total), 0);
```

Comment: sorry, I posted it as an answer before I saw your edit :p

Answer (score 0):

It's simply

```
var array = [
    {data: [1,2,3]},
    {data: [4,5,6]}
];
array.reduce((total, item) => total + item.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b), 0);
// result = 21
```

the second (inner) reduce doesn't have an initial value, so the

- first call: a = data[0], b = data[1]
- second call: a = running total, b = data[2]

see reduce documentation

the first (outer) reduce DOES need an initial value, because the items in it's callback are not numbers